# Fill values ​from one dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: r, sparkr

I have some problems with some processing that I must do in an R environment in Databricks. I have two dataframes.

df1: contains the rows and columns (index1 and index2) and the value to be assigned

| index1 | index2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 142342315 | 1423423341 | A |
| 142342315 | 14234235325 | A |
| 1423423166 | 14234235325 | C |
| 1423423166 | 1423423341 | C |
| ... | ... | ... |

df2: generated by an array with all combinations of index

| rowsname | 142342315 | 1423423166 | 1423423341 | 14234235325 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 142342315 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 1423423166 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 1423423341 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 14234235325 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

The first thing that came to mind is to make a loop to assign the value to each location in the dataframe. Something like that:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    df2[df1$index_1[i], df1$index_2[i]] <- df1$temp[i]
    df2[df1$index_2[i], df1$index_1[i]] <- df1$temp[i]
}
```

But, the problem is that it involves a large number of combinations, several hours of execution.

I tried using sparseMatrix but my indices cannot be converted to integers in this case. Can you think of a way to do it optimally?

I tried for loops, it's so slowly.
I tried using sparseMatrix but my indices cannot be converted to integers in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: `xtabs(value~., df)`

Comment: @SamR thanks for you reply :),
I tried the "spread" method, but I have this problem... I need my matrix to be symmetrical, in this case it only assigns the values [index1, index2] but not [index2, index1]. Now is running a "reshape" function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are looking to produce a square matrix with all names across both dimensions. I think your initial approach should work, if you preallocate the output matrix and replace the for loop with some vectorized version. How about the following?

```
df1 = data.frame(
    index1=c("142342315", "142342315", "1423423166", "1423423166"),
    index2=c("1423423341", "14234235325", "14234235325", "1423423341"),
    value=c("A","A","C","C")
)

rowsname = unique(c(df1$index1,df1$index2))
res = matrix(nrow=length(rowsname),ncol=length(rowsname),dimnames=list(rowsname,rowsname))

lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(r) {
    res[df1$index1[r], df1$index2[r]] <<- df1$value[r]
    res[df1$index2[r], df1$index1[r]] <<- df1$value[r]
})
```

Content of variable "res":

```
            142342315 1423423166 1423423341 14234235325
142342315   NA        NA         "A"        "A"        
1423423166  NA        NA         "C"        "C"        
1423423341  "A"       "C"        NA         NA         
14234235325 "A"       "C"        NA         NA
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your reply. I finally solved it using this:
res[cbind(df$index_1, df$index_2)] <- res[cbind(df$index_2, df$index_1)] <- df$temp

Comment: yes, that's better.